# Why am I getting runtime error running this code?

Tags: c, algorithm, segmentation-fault

I am trying to solve a question on codechef:http://www.codechef.com/problems/SUMTRIAN
problem statement:

```
Let's consider a triangle of numbers in which a number appears in the first line, two numbers appear in the second line, three in the third line, etc. Develop a program which will compute the largest of the sums of numbers that appear on the paths starting from the top towards the base, so that:
on each path the next number is located on the row below, more precisely either directly below or below and one place to the right;
the number of rows is strictly positive, but less than 100
all numbers are positive integers between O and 99.
Input:
2
3
1
2 1
1 2 3
4 
1 
1 2 
4 1 2
2 3 1 1 

Output:
5
9
```

this is the code I submitted:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int maximum(int** s,int row,int col)
{
    int i,j,m[row][col];
    //m[0][0]=s[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i <row; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < row; ++j)
        {
            m[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
        {   

            if(i==0&&j==0)
                m[i][j]=s[i][j];
            else if(j==0)
                m[i][j]=m[i-1][j]+s[i][j];
            else if(i==0)
                m[i][j]=s[i][j];
            else if(m[i-1][j]>m[i-1][j-1])
                m[i][j]=m[i-1][j]+s[i][j];
            else
                m[i][j]=m[i-1][j-1]+s[i][j];
            //printf("m%d %d %d\n",m[i][j],i,j );

        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <row; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < row; ++j)
        {
            //printf("%d\n",m[i][j] );
        }
    }
    int max=0;
    for (i = 0; i <row; ++i)
    {   //printf("%d\n",m[row-1][i] );
        if(m[row-1][i]>max)
            max=m[row-1][i];
    }
    return max;
}


    int main()
    {
        int t;
        scanf("%d",&t);
        while(t--)
        {   
            int n,i,j,*p[10],**pf;

            scanf("%d",&n);
            int s[n][n];
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
                {
                    s[i][j]=0;

                }
            }   
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<=i;j++)
                {
                    scanf("%d",&s[i][j]);

                }
                p[i]=s[i];


            }
            pf=p;

            int sum=maximum((int**)pf,n,n);
            printf("%d\n",sum);


        }



        return 0;
    }
```

this code is giving SIGSEGV.I don't know why?I am not taking much memory.stack is not getting used much .I am initializing every element.The only problem that can be is that of array index out of bounds but I don't think thats happening anywhere.Pls help!

Comment: Please include a sample input and expected output.

Comment: Use `m[row][col] = {0};` to initialize array with `0`.

Comment: it won't change anything!I mean It won't rectify the eroor.

Comment: `pf = p;` is not looking correct in your `main()` as `p` is 1D and `pf` is 2D. And in scanf your value of `n` should be less then `9`.

Comment: https://ideone.com/s5NmPf check this!

Comment: It is the code's way of telling you that you need to give variables meaningful names, so that you have a chance to understand your own code when you encounter a bug.

Comment: The problem is that you've hard-coded the size of `p` at `10` but access it up to `n-1`, which could be anything.

Comment: @Himanshu I want to store the address of p array in pf .so pf=p.

Comment: @ooga Thanks a lot! I don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    for (j = 0; j < row; ++j)
    {
        m[i][j]=0;
    }
```

I think `row` here is supposed to be `col`.

Comment: So why do you have a `col` parameter? You should remove it from your function prototype.

Comment: @user3870509 Theoretically it doesn't matter but anyway. the C standard says extending the bounds of an array results in undefined behavior. Means even in 2D Array declared as `arr[5][5]` It would be accessing out of bounds if you do `arr[1][7]....` Most enviroments support this anyway but just noting it doesn't matter isn't correct at all. Or do you mean row is allways equal to col? Then I'm asking my self, the same as ouah.